# Como faço para mover um triângulo pelos cantos da tela usando java?

Tags: java, java-processing

Eu sou bem novato com java e estou trabalhando no projeto que eu tenho que desenhar um triângulo (que tenho que chamar de alice) que se localiza no canto superior esquerdo da tela e ele tem que se mover em linha reta para o canto superior direito, depois se mover para o inferior direito, depois para o inferior esquerdo e voltar para o ponto inicial superior esquerdo e ele tem que ficar andando pelos cantos da tela até que eu feche e janela.

Eu estou tendo problema com minhas estruturas if. Eu não sei o porque ele sai do ponto inicial (superior direito), vai até o superior esquerdo e depois, quando ele desce para o inferior esquerdo, ele não para na borda da tela, e a partir daí eu não sei se ele não continua a sua trajetória.

Se alguem puder me ajudar eu agradeço de coração.

Meu código está assim:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Alice{
    int colour;
    float xSpeed;
    PApplet parent;
    float x1Pos;
    float y1Pos;
    float x2Pos;
    float y2Pos;
    float x3Pos;
    float y3Pos;

    public Alice(PApplet p, int colour, float x1Pos, float y1Pos, float x2Pos, float y2Pos, float x3Pos, float y3Pos, float xSpeed){
    parent = p;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.x1Pos = x1Pos;
        this.y1Pos = y1Pos;
        this.x2Pos = x2Pos;
        this.y2Pos = y2Pos;
        this.x3Pos = x3Pos;
        this.y3Pos = y3Pos;
        this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
    }

    public void display(){
        parent.rectMode(parent.CENTER);
        parent.fill(colour);
        parent.triangle(x1Pos, y1Pos, x2Pos, y2Pos, x3Pos, y3Pos);
    }

    private void goLeft(){
        this.x1Pos = this.x1Pos - this.xSpeed;
        this.x2Pos = this.x2Pos - this.xSpeed;
        this.x3Pos = this.x3Pos - this.xSpeed;
    }

    private void goRight(){
        this.x1Pos = this.x1Pos + xSpeed;
        this.x2Pos = this.x2Pos + xSpeed;
        this.x3Pos = this.x3Pos + xSpeed;
    }

    private void goUp(){
        this.y1Pos = this.y1Pos - xSpeed;
        this.y2Pos = this.y2Pos - xSpeed;
        this.y3Pos = this.y3Pos - xSpeed;
    }

    private void goDown(){
        this.y1Pos = this.y1Pos + xSpeed;
        this.y2Pos = this.y2Pos + xSpeed;
        this.y3Pos = this.y3Pos + xSpeed;
    }

    public void driveCorner(){
        if(x1Pos <= parent.width - 30){
            goRight();
        }
        if(x1Pos >= parent.width - 30){
            goDown();
        }
        if(y1Pos <= parent.height - 20){
            goLeft();
        }
        if(x1Pos <= 0){ 
         goUp();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que rastreando em variáveis em qual das bordas o triângulo está ou não está, fica bem mais fácil. Além disso, fica melhor se os três vértices forem tratados igualmente quanto a isso sem que seja necessário saber-se de antemão a largura ou a altura do triângulo (no seu código original eram 20 e 30).

Desta forma, o código fica assim:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Alice {
    private int colour;
    private float xSpeed;
    private PApplet parent;
    private float x1Pos;
    private float y1Pos;
    private float x2Pos;
    private float y2Pos;
    private float x3Pos;
    private float y3Pos;

    public Alice(PApplet p, int colour, float x1Pos, float y1Pos, float x2Pos, float y2Pos, float x3Pos, float y3Pos, float xSpeed) {
        parent = p;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.x1Pos = x1Pos;
        this.y1Pos = y1Pos;
        this.x2Pos = x2Pos;
        this.y2Pos = y2Pos;
        this.x3Pos = x3Pos;
        this.y3Pos = y3Pos;
        this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
    }

    public void display() {
        parent.rectMode(parent.CENTER);
        parent.fill(colour);
        parent.triangle(x1Pos, y1Pos, x2Pos, y2Pos, x3Pos, y3Pos);
    }

    private void goLeft() {
        this.x1Pos -= xSpeed;
        this.x2Pos -= xSpeed;
        this.x3Pos -= xSpeed;
    }

    private void goRight() {
        this.x1Pos += xSpeed;
        this.x2Pos += xSpeed;
        this.x3Pos += xSpeed;
    }

    private void goUp() {
        this.y1Pos -= xSpeed;
        this.y2Pos -= xSpeed;
        this.y3Pos -= xSpeed;
    }

    private void goDown() {
        this.y1Pos += xSpeed;
        this.y2Pos += xSpeed;
        this.y3Pos += xSpeed;
    }

    public void driveCorner() {
        boolean naBordaSuperior = y1Pos <= 0 || y2Pos <= 0 || y3Pos <= 0;
        boolean naBordaInferior = y1Pos >= parent.height - 1 || y2Pos >= parent.height - 1 || y3Pos >= parent.height - 1;
        boolean naBordaEsquerda = x1Pos <= 0 || x2Pos <= 0 || x3Pos <= 0;
        boolean naBordaDireita = x1Pos >= parent.width - 1 || x2Pos >= parent.width - 1 || x3Pos >= parent.width - 1;

        if (naBordaSuperior && !naBordaDireita) {
            goRight();
        } else if (naBordaDireita && !naBordaInferior) {
            goDown();
        } else if (naBordaInferior && !naBordaEsquerda) {
            goLeft();
        } else if (naBordaEsquerda && !naBordaSuperior) { 
            goUp();

        // No caso em que o triângulo está no meio e afastado de qualquer borda, vai para a direita.
        } else if (!naBordaSuperior && !naBordaInferior && !naBordaEsquerda && !naBordaDireita) {
            goRight();

        // Este caso só acontece se estiver nas quatro bordas.
        // Ou seja, ou o triângulo é muito grande, ou a tela muito pequena.
        // Portanto, não se move.
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: MUITISSIMO OBRIGADO.
ESTA FUNCIONANDO PERFEITAMENTE